# Data- dash attribute not working in jQuery from ASP.NET Razor foreach loop

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some data- dash attribute in ASP.NET Razor foreach loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model){
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm EditBill" title="EDIT" 
                data-ItemId = "@item.Id">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
            </a> 
}
```

The jQuery code works as follows:

```
$('.EditBill').click(function () {
     var ItemId = $(this).attr('data-ItemId');
});
```

But the following replacement is not working (return 'undefined' from debugger):

```
$('.EditBill').click(function () {
      var ItemId = $(this).data('ItemId');
}
```

Can anyone advise? Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers automatically converts attributes to lower-case and in method `.data(key)` the parameter `key` is case-sensitive. So use lower-case i.e. `.data('itemid')`

Additionally you can use [`Element.dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to access the same

```js
console.log($('.EditBill').data('itemid'), $('.EditBill')[0].dataset);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm EditBill" title="EDIT" data-ItemId="Yahoooooooo">
                1
            </a>
```